# hub 6-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports!

Tags: kernel, drivers, usb

AMD CPU:

```
 green kernel: usb usb6: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
 green kernel: usb usb6: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 6.02
 green kernel: usb usb6: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
 green kernel: usb usb6: Product: xHCI Host Controller
 green kernel: usb usb6: Manufacturer: Linux 6.2.9-arch1-1 xhci-hcd
 green kernel: usb usb6: SerialNumber: 0000:34:00.0
 green kernel: hub 6-0:1.0: USB hub found
 green kernel: hub 6-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports!
```

I saw some similar issues but no answer yet.

ex:
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=284843